# Why does this cout << pow(-3, (1.0 / 3)) return -nan(ind)?

Tags: c++, pow

Why does this:

```
cout << pow(-3, (1.0 / 3))
```

return

```
-nan(ind)
```

whereas

```
pow(-3, 3)
```

and

```
pow(3, (1.0 / 3))
```

both work fine ?

Answer (score 3):

The pow function is used only for positive numbers.

See the man page of [pow function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/powf):

> If x is a finite value less than 0, and y is a finite noninteger,  a
>   domain error occurs, and a NaN is returned.

To get the power of number you can try like this:

```
int main() {
    int exp;
    float base, power = 1;

    cout << "Base and exponent :  ";
    cin >> base >> exp;

    while (exp != 0) {
        power *= base;
        --exp;
    }

    cout << "Output = " << power;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: soo, how do i calculate x^y when x<0 and y is a noninteger?

Comment: @MaverickS:- Updated my answer. Please check!

Answer (score 3):

`pow(x, y)` for floating point types is probably implemented as `exp(y * ln(x))`.

`ln(x)` fails for negative numbers, or zero.

For a full reference, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow

Answer (score 3):

This is because mathematically the fractional power of a negative number delivers a complex number.

[Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) for std::pow states that "`pow(base, exp)` returns NaN and raises FE_INVALID if base is finite and negative and exp is finite and non-integer."

Comment: Um, mathematically you most certainly can: the answer is not real though.

Comment: yes, sorry, you can if you allow for complex numbers

Comment: This would be a nice answer if you rephrased that mathematical dogma.

Answer (score 1):

This is plain mathemetics:

- pow(-3, 3) ==> (-3)<sup>3</sup>
- pow(3, (1.0 / 3) ==> 3<sup>1/3</sup> = <sup>3</sup>√3
- pow(-3, (1.0 / 3) ==> (-3)<sup>1/3</sup> = <sup>3</sup>√(-3) ==> Not possible, you cannot take the root of a negative number. It is imaginary.

Comment: But it's still possible. It's just that `pow(double, double)` does't support it. And your second statement is not correct, there are three cube roots: you've only picked the one on the real line.

Comment: How is it possible to take a root of a negative number in the real world? The answer is imaginary = <sup3</sup>√3 * i. What is not correct in my second statement?

Comment: @Bathsheba, it is perfectly valid to look at mathematics as not including imaginary numbers.  Mathematics is not one universal system with inherent rules.  It is a variety of systems each of which has decided (rather than inherent) rules.  When doing computer programming with doubles, the system of mathematics in which there are no imaginary numbers is most likely what is intended.  They are called "imaginary" for a reason.

Comment: Indeed, although I find "plain mathematics" dogmatic and imprecise.

Comment: Can you please explain what is imprecise?  I cannot imagine a language that produces a float or double result for a negative square root. Because it would violate mathematical conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the list of special case on the [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) pow page:

Errors are reported as specified in math_errhandling.

If base is finite and negative and exp is finite and non-integer, a domain error occurs and a range error may occur.

If base is zero and exp is zero, a domain error may occur.

If base is zero and exp is negative, a domain error or a pole error may occur.

If the implementation supports IEEE floating-point arithmetic (IEC 60559),

- `pow(+0, exp)`, where exp is a negative odd integer, returns +∞ and raises FE_DIVBYZERO
- `pow(-0, exp)`, where exp is a negative odd integer, returns -∞ and raises FE_DIVBYZERO
- `pow(±0, exp)`, where exp is negative, finite, and is an even integer or a non-integer, - returns +∞ and raises FE_DIVBYZERO
- `pow(±0, -∞)` returns +∞ and may raise FE_DIVBYZERO
- `pow(+0, exp)`, where exp is a positive odd integer, returns +0
- `pow(-0, exp)`, where exp is a positive odd integer, returns -0
- `pow(±0, exp)`, where exp is positive non-integer or a positive even integer, returns +0
- `pow(-1, ±∞)` returns 1
- `pow(+1, exp)` returns 1 for any exp, even when exp is NaN
- `pow(base, ±0)` returns 1 for any base, even when base is NaN
- `pow(base, exp)` returns NaN and raises FE_INVALID if base is finite and negative and exp is finite and non-integer.
- `pow(base, -∞)` returns +∞ for any |base|<1
- `pow(base, -∞)` returns +0 for any |base|>1
- `pow(base, +∞)` returns +0 for any |base|<1
- `pow(base, +∞)` returns +∞ for any |base|>1
- `pow(-∞, exp)` returns -0 if exp is a negative odd integer
- `pow(-∞, exp)` returns +0 if exp is a negative non-integer or even integer
- `pow(-∞, exp)` returns -∞ if exp is a positive odd integer
- `pow(-∞, exp)` returns +∞ if exp is a positive non-integer or even integer
- `pow(+∞, exp)` returns +0 for any negative exp
- `pow(+∞, exp)` returns +∞ for any positive exp
  except where specified above, if any argument is NaN, NaN is returned